# Help identify grey animal (?)

Tags: set-identification

So I have this half assembled grey piece.
My guess would be an animal, maybe from Ninjago series, or AT walker from Star Wars, but unlikely.

Timeline maybe from 2015 upwards.
Google photo search failed to be of help.
[image: ff]
[image: ss]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Erumpent creature from LEGO® Fantastic Beasts™ [Newt's Case of Magical Creatures (75952)](https://brickset.com/sets/75952-1/Newt-s-Case-of-Magical-Creatures) set.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!